# Probability of heads given we observe HTH?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am observing a sequence of heads and tails and trying to deduce the bias of my coin.

[image]

Let's say I observe `HTH`.  Can I estimate the bias of my coin $p$ ?  Using [Bayes formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem), 
\begin{align} \mathbb{P}[p = x \pm \epsilon \big|\, HTH ] &=& \frac{ \mathbb{P}[HTH\big| \,p = x \pm \epsilon ]\; \mathbb{P}[p = x \pm \epsilon]}{\mathbb{P}[ HTH ]} \\
&\propto & \mathbb{P}[HTH\big|\, p = x \pm \epsilon ]\; \mathbb{P}[p = x \pm \epsilon]\end{align}

---

- My 3 coin flips are independent, so $\mathbb{P}[HTH]= p^2(1-p)$.
- I think we have to make assumption of the possible values of $p$, like $\mathbb{P}[p = x \pm \epsilon] = 2\epsilon $
- Given no prior observation $\mathbb{P}[ HTH ] = \tfrac{1}{8}$ ?  It's not clear what to put here.

I think I am deriving the [$\beta$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) $d\mu =  x^a(1-x)^b dx $.  Is there a name for the assumptions I am using here?  The term might be [conjugate prior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior#Example).

---

What happened to the normalization?  I get:

$$  \frac{ \mathbb{P}[HTH\big|\, p = x \pm \epsilon ]\; \mathbb{P}[p = x \pm \epsilon]}{\mathbb{P}[ HTH ]} = 
\frac{ x^2 (1-x) 2\epsilon }{\tfrac{1}{8}} = 16\epsilon \cdot x^2(1-x) $$

What does this factor $\boxed{16\epsilon}$ mean?  How do I get the correct weight?

Answer (score 0):

You will find it easier if you treat $p$ as having a continuous distribution with a prior density $\pi_0(p)$ and look for a posterior density $\pi(p|HTH)$.

Your posterior distribution would then be $$\pi(p|HTH) = \dfrac{\pi_0(p)\; \mathbb{P}(HTH|p)}{\mathbb{P}(HTH)}=\dfrac{ \pi_0(p) \; p^2(1-p)}{\displaystyle \int_{q=0}^1 \pi_0(q) \; q^2(1-q) \; dq}.$$

Using a conjugate prior of a Beta distribution makes the calculations easier (not always a good reason for choosing it): if $\pi_0(p) \sim B(\alpha,\beta)$ then $\pi(p|HTH) \sim B(\alpha+2,\beta+1)$.  The mean of the posterior distribution is then $\frac{\alpha+2}{\alpha+\beta+3}$.  If you started with a uniform prior distribution for $p$ (again, not always a good choice, especially not with a coin), i.e. $\alpha = \beta = 1$, then your posterior mean would be $\frac{3}{5}$.